# Performance update/select on large datasets - tcl hash maps (arrays) vs. PostgreSQL 9.4 temporary table

Tags: arrays, postgresql, performance, tcl, temp-tables

Assuming we have a data set of 800k key/value pairs. Key is a date string of type 'YYYY-MM-DD-STRING1-STRING-2'. We want to select or update all records with key '2017-09-*'.

Based on testing scripts 'select' or 'update' on data stored in PostgreSQL 9.4 temporary table performs 2x better than operating on tcl's hash maps (arrays) using "foreach key", "lsort" and "string match" or "regexp".

From a SysArchitect point of view, is there anything that would speak against preferring temporary tables over tcl arrays when it comes to operate on large data sets? Any limiting factors or pitfalls that would speak against using temporary tables in such scenarios?

Comment: You might also want to compare with Tcl dictionaries; arrays have some tricky aspects with trace handling which requires a double iteration when doing many bulk operations.